# Verified by Visa on orders over $100

Tags: magento, payment-gateway, magento-1.9, payment-method

I need to configure a payment method that uses Verified by Visa only if the order total is above $100.

I can configure a payment method (such as Moneris or Authorize.net) to use Verified by Visa above $100

[image]

but I want to be able to use the same payment gateway for orders under $100 but without Verified by Visa.

My guess is that I could somehow list the payment method twice but then configure it differently:

```
- Name:                Moneris (<$100)
  Maximum Order Total: $99.99
  3D Secure:           No

- Name:                Moneris (>=$100)
  Minimum Order Total: $100
  3D Secure:           Yes
```

Is it possible to list a payment method twice like this somehow? Do I need to make a custom Payment Method Module like this? http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/payment/create-payment-method-module Or is there someway to copy and update an existing one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you have to create another payment method for this. Since I didn't see your code. So I can tell the logic only.

Just disable minimum order. So we can place all order using this payment method. And add simple logic in your code that verify the order by **VISA** only if order is greater than **$100** or as per you want. Like,

```
<?php
$quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$quoteData= $quote->getData();
$grandTotal=$quoteData['grand_total'];

if($grandTotal >= 100) {
$verify_visa = true;
}
```

I don't know how they verify the order by visa in your payment gateway method. If you post that code here I will help you to solve this. Happy coding..!

If you have any doubt please comment here.